# How to declare two or multiple words as a single word although it contain space

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am creating a search for blood donors and everything is working fine and after completing the search I am facing some issues in it. My search is working but it's not showing perfect result. Let me elaborate,

```
#My Table Structure

    #Table 1- blood_donor
    +----+------+----------+-------------+
    | id | name | blood_id | location_id | // columns
    +----+------+----------+-------------+
    |  1 | rony |     1    |       1     |
    +----+------+----------+-------------+
    |  2 | jony |     2    |       2     |
    +----+------+----------+-------------+
    |  3 | tony |     3    |       3     |
    +----+------+----------+-------------+ // Data example

    #Table 2- blood_group
    +----+------------+
    | id | group_name | // columns
    +----+------------+
    |  1 | a positive |
    +----+------------+
    |  2 | b positive |
    +----+------------+
    |  3 | o negative |
    +----+------------+ // Data example

    #Table 3- location
    +----+---------------+
    | id | location_name | // columns
    +----+---------------+
    |  1 |     khulna    |
    +----+---------------+
    |  2 |     dhaka     |
    +----+---------------+
    |  3 |     sylhet    |
    +----+---------------+ // Data example
```

My keyword

```php
$keyword = "o negative blood donor in khulna";
```

Now I separated the words

```php
$keyword_array = explode(" ",$keyword);
```

Here is my query

```php
$query ="SELECT * FROM 
    blood_donor AS bd
LEFT JOIN blood_group AS bg ON bg.id = bd.blood_id
LEFT JOIN location    AS lo ON lo.id = bd.location_id
WHERE
bd.name          LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
bg.group_name    LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
lo.location_name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR";

// this above part giving me a result set for 100% match for the full keyword

// Now I generate another result set for separated keyword below

if (count($keyword_array) > 1) {
    foreach ($keyword_array as $array) {
        $query = $query . " 
            bd.name          LIKE '%$array%' OR
            bg.group_name    LIKE '%$array%' OR
            lo.location_name LIKE '%$array%' OR";
    }
}
                                            
$query = substr($query,0,-3); // Removed the extra OR from the end

// My order by section
$query = $query . " ORDER BY 
    CASE
        // If full match found, then bring them top
        WHEN bd.name LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN 1";
        
        // If partial match found, then bring them afterwards
        if (count($keyword_array) > 1) {
            $keyword_count = count($keyword_array);
            $query = $query . " WHEN"; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < $keyword_count; $i++) {
                $query = $query . " bd.name LIKE '%$keyword_array[$i]%' AND";
            }
            $query = substr($query,0,-3); // To remove the last AND
            $query = $query . " THEN 2";
        }
        $query = $query . " ELSE 3
    END
LIMIT $items_to_skip, $items_per_page"; // These two variables are OFFSET and LIMIT
```

The keyword I am searching with, in the full match section it has nothing to do because there are no such sentence available in my database as `o negative blood donor in khulna that is okay but when the keywords getting separated then in the separated result section it's generating result what actually I am not looking for!

My separated keywords generating an array which is

```php
Array
(
    [0] => o
    [1] => negative
    [2] => blood
    [3] => donor
    [4] => in
    [5] => khulna
)
```

And my SQL generating the query like this

```sql
bd.name          LIKE '%o%'        OR
bg.group_name    LIKE '%o%'        OR
lo.location_name LIKE '%o%'        OR
bd.name          LIKE '%negative%' OR
bg.group_name    LIKE '%negative%' OR
lo.location_name LIKE '%negative%' OR
bd.name          LIKE '%blood%'    OR
bg.group_name    LIKE '%blood%'    OR
lo.location_name LIKE '%blood%'    OR
bd.name          LIKE '%donor%'    OR
bg.group_name    LIKE '%donor%'    OR
lo.location_name LIKE '%donor%'    OR
bd.name          LIKE '%in%'       OR
bg.group_name    LIKE '%in%'       OR
lo.location_name LIKE '%in%'       OR
bd.name          LIKE '%khulna%'   OR
bg.group_name    LIKE '%khulna%'   OR
lo.location_name LIKE '%khulna%'
```

This query giving me all the three rows because all the name contain the letter `o` but I don't want that! I want `o negative` as a single word so the result must be two rows. row 1 and 3. But how to achieve that? I really can't figure it out. Also I don't know how to make two different word as a single word.

There are eight blood groups and I want to treat every blood group name as a single word!
Example: A Negative is two word, but I want them as one word and how am I going to do it, is it possible?

I need an array like this. And how to do it?

```php
$keyword = "o negative blood donor in khulna";
$keyword_array = explode(" ",$keyword);
print_r($keyword_array);
Array
(
    [0] => o negative
    [1] => blood
    [2] => donor
    [3] => in
    [4] => khulna
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pattern to match the words that you want:

```
(?i)\b[abo]\s+(?:posi|nega)tive\b|\S+
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for a case insensitive match
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[abo]\s+` match either `a` `b` or  `o` and 1 or more whitespace characters
- `(?:posi|nega)tive\b` Match either positive or negative followed by a word boundary
- `|` Or
- `\S+` Match 1 or more non whitespace chars (All other words)

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pVLea2/1) or a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/bt94p).

```
$keyword = "o negative blood donor in khulna";
$pattern = "/(?i)\b[abo]\s+(?:posi|nega)tive\b|\S+/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $keyword, $keyword_array);
print_r($keyword_array[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => o negative
    [1] => blood
    [2] => donor
    [3] => in
    [4] => khulna
)
```

Comment: How to add ab from the keyword in it `[abo]\s+` for ab positive or negative blood group. It's working with a b and o groups but not with ab.

Comment: @Bearded You could use an alternation to match ab as well like `(?i)\b(?:[abo]|ab)\s+(?:posi|nega)tive\b|\S+` See https://regex101.com/r/eqCQFn/1

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

preg_match_all('/(\w\s+)?\w+/', 'o negative blood donor in khulna', $matches);
$keyword_array = $matches[0];
```

and here is an advice: please use [prepared statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) for SQL

Comment: what if I want to search for `ab negative blood donor in khulna` what will be the pattern then? Its working with a, b and o but not with ab.

Comment: depends how smart you want this search to be, it could be very complicated

Answer (score 1):

Create a "special" variable, remove that variable/string from `$keyword`, explode your `$keyword` and add the "special" variable back to the resulting array:

```
<?php
$special = 'o negative';
$keyword = "o negative blood donor in khulna";
$keyword = trim(str_replace($special, '', $keyword));
$keyword_array = explode(" ",$keyword);
$keyword_array[] = $special;
print_r($keyword_array);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => blood
    [1] => donor
    [2] => in
    [3] => khulna
    [4] => o negative
)
```

Edit:
To use multiple keywords to be replaced you can use this:

```
<?php
$specials = array('a positive','b negative','o negative','ab positive');
$keyword = "o negative blood donor in khulna";
foreach($specials as $special) {
    if(strstr($keyword, $special)) {
        $keyword = trim(str_replace($special, '', $keyword));
        $found[] = $special;
    }
}
$keyword_array = explode(" ",$keyword);
$keyword_array = array_merge($keyword_array, $found);
print_r($keyword_array);
```

If a "special" keyword was found it will be replaced in the original string and saved to a `$found` array. Your `$keyword_array` will be merged with the `$found` array in the end.

This will also work if you have multiple of those "special" keywords in your original string: Using `$keyword = "o negative b negative blood donor in khulna a positive";` would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => blood
    [1] => donor
    [2] => in
    [3] => khulna
    [4] => a positive
    [5] => b negative
    [6] => o negative
)
```

Comment: `$special = array('a positive','b negative','o negative','ab positive')` How to integrate this array in it?

Comment: Move your special words with "double" groups to the front so they get replaced first: `$specials = array('ab positive', 'ab negative', 'b positive', 'a positive','b negative','o negative',);`. Personally though I think I'd make the blood types a checkbox on the form so you can explicitly search them by id, not fulltext. For any further questions you post I suggest you post the _complete_  requirements in your first draft, those have changed twice now

Comment: It will be great If I do the checkbox but not all the users are going to click the checkbox, and I want to provide what they are looking for whether it is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have an issue with blood group/type, as it is like "O negative" or "AB positive" or "0 +"...and so on, so basically two words in one...Try this (its not optimal, but it does the job)

```
  // Define blood groups and types here..You can also include more later 
    $bloodGroups = [
        "negative",
        "positive",
        "+",
        "-"
        ];
   
    $bloodTypes = [
        "a",
        "b",
        "o",
        "0", //Some might go for zero...
        "ab"
        ];
     
    $keyword = "o negative blood donor in khulna";
    // Also try with...So upper case, signs, number
    // $keyword = "AB - blood donor in khulna";
    // $keyword = "0 + blood donor in khulna";

    $keywordArray = explode(" ",$keyword);
    
    // Array to push blood group and type
    $bloodGroupType= [];
    
    
    foreach($keywordArray as $key => $value) {
        $value = strtolower($value);
        //If found in bloodTypes array, we have a blood type...push it to first position in bloodGroupType array and also unset from main array
        if(in_array($value, $bloodTypes )) {
            // Number to char
             if($value == "0") {
                $value = "o";
            }
            $bloodGroupType[0] = $value;
            unset($keywordArray[$key]);
        }
        //If value is found in groups array, we have a blood group...push it to second position in bloodGroupType array and also unset from main array
        if (in_array($value, $bloodGroups )) {
            //Change signs to words
            if($value == "-") {
                $value = "negative";
            }
             if($value == "+") {
                $value = "positive";
            }
             $bloodGroupType[1] = $value;
             unset($keywordArray[$key]);
        }
    }
    // Create string from bloodGroupType, and push to "main array"
    $searchBloodType = implode(" ", $bloodGroupType);
    
    array_push($keywordArray,$searchBloodType);
    print_r($keywordArray);
```

So now you can loop over this array. Also..This solution will also work if you mix the string..

BR

Comment: with a single blood group, it is working but the indexing getting removed but when I am using the keyword as `o negative b positive ab positive and ab negative blood donor in khulna` then it's only showing `ab negative` first three is getting removed.